# When I install create-react-app , I get a 'network Socket timeout' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

```
$ npx create-react-app amazon-clone

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

Creating a new React app in D:\js\faceboom.

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\CCS LAPTOP HYD\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-09-15T13_21_13_774Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting amazon-clone/ from D:\js
Done.
```

Comment: So it says you have bad network settings - have you investigated that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Clear your cache using the below command:

```
$ npm cache clean --force
```

and then try again creating the react app

```
npx create-react-app amazon-clone
```

If that doesn't work, try providing a `timeout` option:

```
npx create-react-app amazon-clone -timeout=60000
```

Comment: your solution is not working

Comment: You could increase the timeout time if 60 sec not working for you. It should work.

Comment: ```npx create-react-app amazon-clone -timeout=60000```  this one worked for me.